# Efficiently indicate meeting a condition by group

Tags: r

I have subjects who may experience an event. If they do experience it then they should have no more records
(and they should not experience the event again).
I am trying to highlight records that do not satisfy this.

In the example below, id's 3 and 4 are problematic.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:4, each=3), time=1:3, 
                 outcome = c(0,0,0, 0,0,1, 0,1,0, 0,1,1))
df
#    id time outcome
# 1   1    1       0
# 2   1    2       0
# 3   1    3       0
# 4   2    1       0
# 5   2    2       0
# 6   2    3       1
# 7   3    1       0
# 8   3    2       1
# 9   3    3       0
# 10  4    1       0
# 11  4    2       1
# 12  4    3       1
```

My attempt - gets there but is inefficient (my data is ~ 4GB so i am running into ram problems)

```
df$yy <- with(df, time* outcome)
df$ll <- with(df, ave(id, id, FUN=length))

df$temp <- with(df, outcome==1 & yy != ll)
df$warn <- with(df, ave(temp, id, FUN=function(X) any(X)))
df
#    id time outcome yy ll  temp  warn
# 1   1    1       0  0  3 FALSE FALSE
# 2   1    2       0  0  3 FALSE FALSE
# 3   1    3       0  0  3 FALSE FALSE
# 4   2    1       0  0  3 FALSE FALSE
# 5   2    2       0  0  3 FALSE FALSE
# 6   2    3       1  3  3 FALSE FALSE
# 7   3    1       0  0  3 FALSE  TRUE
# 8   3    2       1  2  3  TRUE  TRUE
# 9   3    3       0  0  3 FALSE  TRUE
# 10  4    1       0  0  3 FALSE  TRUE
# 11  4    2       1  2  3  TRUE  TRUE
# 12  4    3       1  3  3 FALSE  TRUE
```

Could you suggest a more efficient way to proceed please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested for memory efficiency, but I'd imagine this will be much more efficient, try the following

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, warn := sum(outcome) > outcome[.N], by = id]
df
#     id time outcome  warn
#  1:  1    1       0 FALSE
#  2:  1    2       0 FALSE
#  3:  1    3       0 FALSE
#  4:  2    1       0 FALSE
#  5:  2    2       0 FALSE
#  6:  2    3       1 FALSE
#  7:  3    1       0  TRUE
#  8:  3    2       1  TRUE
#  9:  3    3       0  TRUE
# 10:  4    1       0  TRUE
# 11:  4    2       1  TRUE
# 12:  4    3       1  TRUE
```

Comment: By the way, you can shorten the logical expression in line 3 to "indx>outval"... that is unless the outcome column isn't binary in general.

Comment: The reason I did it in two steps is in order to reduce the operations while using `by = id` to minimal. This is usually the bottleneck when there are many unique ids within a big data set. If you notice, the last line doesn't include the `by = id` argument in order to speed things up. Though now when I saw  Bridgeburners comment I came up with a nice one liner. See Edit.